# Join a ruby enumerator into a string

Tags: ruby, generator, enumerator

I have an instance of `Enumerator::Generator` that yields strings. I need to join them into a single string.

What's a good way of doing this? I notice that `*` doesn't work. I know I can `.map {|x| x}` first but that seems rather un-idiomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case I' might reach for `inject`/[`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aliases for the same method, `reduce` as a name makes more sense, to me) with the `+` operator:

```
enum.reduce(:+)
# or, passing in a block
enum.reduce(&:+)
```

As a full example:

```
# never used Enumerator::Generator directly, but you called it out specifically
# in your question, and this seems to be doing the trick to get it working
enum = Enumerator::Generator.new do |y|
  y.yield "ant"
  y.yield "bear"
  y.yield "cat"
end

p enum.reduce(&:+) # output: "antbearcat"
# crude example of modifying the strings as you join them
p enum.reduce('') { |memo, word| memo += word.upcase + ' ' }
# output: "ANT BEAR CAT "
```

Comment: nice! hand't thought to `reduce`

Comment: `String#<<` is [better](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#string-concatenation) than `String#+`.

Comment: @cremno Yeah, though you better give a starting value: `enum.reduce("", :<<)`, or one might be surprised if the first string in `enum` is saved somewhere :) `arr = ["foo", "bar"]; enum = arr.to_enum; p enum.reduce(:<<); p arr` shows the degenerate case.

Comment: Another reason to give `reduce` a starting value: `enum = [].each; enum.reduce(:<<) #=> nil` whereas I would think one would generally want `enum.reduce("", :<<) #=>  ""`. Even if one were confident that that array of strings were non-empty this would provide insurance.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=["Raja","gopalan"].to_enum #let's assume this is your enumerator
```

Write the following code

```
p a.map(&:itself).join
```

Or

```
p a.to_a.join
```

output

```
"Rajagopalan"
```

Comment: You can simply write `to_a` instead of `map(&:itself)`.